# Why is there an error with snapshot.data.length?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to parse data from an API. For that, I am using FutureBuilder to list all the parsed data in a ListView.

I've performed a check for nullity of `snapshot.data` but I keep on getting this error in the segment `snapshot.data.length`, it says, `The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

I've a similar error in the `snapshot.data[i]` section, which says `The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

Here is my code's section of the same:

```
 body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData('hello'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                child: Text("Loading"),
              );
            }else{
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: snapshot.data[i].partOfSpeech,
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Here's getData(String s):

```
Future<List> getData(String s) async {
  var response = await http
      .get(Uri.https('api.dictionaryapi.dev', 'api/v2/entries/en_US/' + s));
  var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body)[0];

  List<Data> data = [];

  for (var x in jsonData["meanings"]) {
    String definition = x["definitions"][0]["definition"];
    Data d = Data(x["partOfSpeech"], definition);
    data.add(d);
  }

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if u are using a new version of flutter (2.2.0 or above). first try adding a null check to the target ('!'). because of the null safety feature.

```
 body: Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: getData('hello'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container(
            child: Text("Loading"),
          );
        }else{
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: snapshot.data[i].partOfSpeech,
                );
              });
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
```

then try specifying the FutureBuilder type to a List of Data type

```
 body: Container(
    child: FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
      future: getData('hello'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container(
            child: Text("Loading"),
          );
        }else{
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: snapshot.data[i].partOfSpeech,
                );
              });
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 5):

In continuation to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68174708/10951873),
I found the solution to my problem. Apparently getData was not returning a List as intended. Instead, it was returning an Object.

***Typecasting* the Object to List solved the problem.**

Here's the corrected code:

```
body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData('hello'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                child: Text("Loading"),
              );
            }else{
              //typecasting Object to List
              var data = (snapshot.data as List<Data>).toList();
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: data[i].partOfSpeech,
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Put 'AsyncSnapshot' before snapshot in the builder parameter.

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking that `snapshot.data` is not null you can do the following to fix it.

```
 body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData('hello'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(
                child: Text("Loading"),
              );
            } else{
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: snapshot.data[i]!.partOfSpeech,
                    );
                  });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: After changing the line to `itemCount: snapshot.data!.length`, a new error is being generated: `The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.`

Comment: Can you check what type `snapshot.data` is?

Comment: just checked using `snapshot.data.runtimeType`, got the result as `List<Data>`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look at is the result of `getData('hello')`

Apparently, it does not return something that has a length property.

Comment: it returns a `List`

Comment: but how is that related to my problem?

Comment: For getting the right answer, you need to share also getData method on your question. In your another answer I saw you shared: `The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.` this means, getData method (sometimes) returning Object instead of list. Thats how its related.